# MySQL multi-table update

Tags: mysql, update

I'm a bit confused about the proper way to update one table, based on the values of corresponding rows in another table.

Here is the query I have:

```
UPDATE
    features,
    images
SET
    features.deleted = 1
WHERE
    features.objectType = 'image'
    AND images.id = features.objectId
    AND images.uploaded = 0;
```

**My goal:**

> I want to set the `features.deleted` column value for all rows in the
>   `features` table to be `1`, only if the corresponding
>   `images.uploaded` value for that associated image is `0`.

**Business logic:**

> I want to go over all the images that been created in my app, and if
>   the image wasn't successfully uploaded, I want to delete the
>   corresponding `features` record.

I believe this works, but have been having a hard time finding specific examples using my approach (most suggest using `join`s).

My concern is that the `UPDATE` query is too general: I just want to make sure that it will ***only*** update `feature` records that have their associated `image` record with an `uploaded` value of `0`.

Thanks for any guidance/confirmation!

Comment: It would help if you can provide the table definition (SHOW CREATE TABLE) for features and images tables. However, the answer may be similar to the one provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was correct, and the query above worked as desired. For anyone stumbling on this in the future, the format seemed to work given my context.

```
UPDATE
    features,
    images
SET
    features.deleted = 1
WHERE
    features.objectType = 'image'
    AND images.id = features.objectId
    AND images.uploaded = 0;
```

Thanks for your time everyone :)